# Question on finding ith column of Inverse Matrix from two basis vector linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Here is the question,

"Let A be an invertible Matrix. Suppose

$$ Au = 5e_1 + 6e_2 + 7e_3 + 8e_4 $$
$$ Av = 5e_1 + 6e_2 + 9e_3 + 8e_4 $$
Where $e_i \epsilon \Re^4 $ is the $i^{th}$ standard basis vector. In terms of **u** and **v** find the third column of $A^{-1}$

My first thought is that I can represent **v** and **u** as 
$$v = [5\;6\; 9\; 8\;]A^{-1} $$
$$u = [5\; 6\; 7\; 8\;]A^{-1} $$
Which gives me the Matrix in **u** and **v** forms. But I am a little confused as to where to go from here. I feel like each column in $A^{-1} **v** and **u** are both 4*1 vectors meaning A is a 4*4 matrix. This  is derived from the space we are in. That means that this 4*1 vector for each equation would be equal to the Inverse times that vector. But where do I go from here with this logic??

There was a hint at the end that the once the logic is worked out there is essentially no calculations at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are writing vectors as column vectors when using matrix multiplication. You should be thinking of $u$ as a column vector of four numbers (the coefficients in the standard basis), then
$$
Au =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
8 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
Av =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
5 \\
6 \\
9 \\
8 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
So then, what column vector is $w$ if I say
$$ \frac{1}{2} A(v-u) = w \; ?  $$
What happens when you multiply both sides of that on the left by $A^{-1} \; ? \;$

Comment: So when you multiply Both Sides by the inverse of A you get $w*A^{-1}$ and then $1/2(v-u)$ equals that. I am not great with column vectors. But I do not know what column vector $w$ is then? Looking at that I would think you distribute A over to v and u and then plug in the vectors. But I am also curious as to where you got this equation.

Comment: @icoder  I just used $w$ as a name. Especially, it should be $A^{-1} w= \frac{1}{2} A^{-1}A (v-u).$ I guess I should add that $A(v-u) = Av - Au$ and is (must be!!) a column vector

Comment: OHHH THat makes so much sense! But my only issue is where did you get the formula to find $1/2A(v-u) = w$ Like I get that $w$ is a variable but what about the the $1/2A(v-u)$ ??

Comment: So is the answer [0010]? That is what I got when I plug that all in

Comment: @icoder as a column vector!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much